# Conceptual Differences among Galerkin Methods

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-derivative

I have a conceptual question about numerical methods for second-order elliptic partial differential equations.

What is the difference among finite element, continuous finite element, discontinuous finite element, continuous galerkin and discontinuous galerkin methods? Are some of them just the same thing?

Comment: These are categories of methods for approximating solutions to partial differential equations.  Galerkin methods are a broader category than finite element methods, or to say the same thing, finite elements are a special case of Galerkin methods.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath. So in which sense galerkin methods are a boarder category ? Is it something like say, discontinuous finite element and discontinuous finite volume are both sub categories of discontinuous galerkin methods?

Comment: As you seem to be a new participant here, I would recommend you add some context to the Question.  This would help Readers to grasp what level of understanding you aim to get.  I think a brief explanation of the distinction between Galerkin methods and finite elements methods would be the kind of content Math.SE values, but the multiple terms you ask about could make for a quite broad discussion.

Comment: I don't need you to have a deep knowledge, but I want to write something that you will find educational.  So it would matter if you knew the kinds of problems these numerical methods are developed to solve, for example.

Answer (score 3):

All numerical methods for approximating the solution of differential equations address the infinite dimensionality of function spaces in which an exact solution is postulated by constructing a finite dimensional analog which can provide a suitable approximation.  This is true of finite difference methods as well as finite element methods.

[Galerkin methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method) are useful in approximating solutions to systems of differential equations (and sometimes more general problems) that have *weak* or *variational formulations*.

A typical example is a second-order elliptic PDE in a simply connected domain $\Omega$ of the plane, with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions:

$$ a u_{xx} + b u_{xy} + c u_{yy} = f \;\; \text{ on } \Omega $$
$$ u = 0 \;\; \text{ on } \partial \Omega $$

which has a weak formulation obtained by multiplying by a "test function" $v$ and performing integration by parts:

$$ A(u,v) = F(v) \;\; \forall v $$

where $A(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a bilinear form (on a suitable function space) and $F$ is a linear functional on that space.

While the "classical" or *strong* solution to the PDE may be sought in a function space such as $\mathcal{C}^2(\Omega)$, requiring two continuous derivatives (up to the boundary), the weak formulation allows us to "split" the order of differentiation between the "trial function" $u$ and the "test function" $v$.  Reducing the required "smoothness" of derivatives (here, from second-order continuous derivatives to square integrable first-order derivatives) allows us to work with fairly simple classes of functions in *approximating* the solutions to the classical problem.

That is, if $V = \mathcal{W}_0^1(\Omega)$ is the Sobolev space of functions on $\Omega$ with square integrable first-order derivatives and "trace" zero on the boundary, then a finite dimensional subspace $V_n \subset V$ may be used to get a discrete *Galerkin approximation scheme* by solving the *weak formulation* of the problem on $V_n$:

$$ A(\hat{u},\hat{v}) = F(\hat{v}) \;\; \forall \hat{v} \in V_n $$

This leads to a system of linear equations to solve, given a basis for $V_n$, of size $n\times n$ where $\dim(V_n) = n$.  Ellipticity of the PDE implies that the bilinear form $A(\cdot,\cdot)$ is *coercive*, and this in turn implies that the discretized solution (finitely many unknowns) is a *quasi-optimal approximation* of the weak solution $u \in V$.  Here quasi-optimal means that the error of approximation $||u - \hat{u}||_{\mathcal{W}^1}$ is within a constant factor of the error of the best approximation available in $V_n$.  [Note: The constant factor will depend on the coefficients of the elliptic PDE and on the domain $\Omega$.]

[Finite element methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) are a subset of these in which the approximating subspaces $V_n$ are constructed by geometric subdivision of $\Omega$ and trial/test functions that are defined piecewise on those subdivisions ("elements") in a way that achieves the required smoothness of functions in $V$.  For example we might *triangulate* the domain $\Omega$ and work with approximating functions that are piecewise linear (but continuous) with respect to that triangulation.

Now there are many variations on this theme.  What we've described above are *conforming* Galerkin (resp. finite element) methods, in which the subset relation $V_n \subset V$ of the discrete and infinite dimensional function spaces holds.  Some of the terms asked about in the Question concern *non-conforming* approximation schemes, where we may allow smoothness of the functions to be further reduced.

Thus [Discontinuous Galerkin methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_Galerkin_method) are in the category of non-conforming approximation schemes (discretizations).  In practice for elliptical problems these are also implemented as *hybrid* methods, meaning that the trial functions are two-part combinations of functions on "elements" (such as triangles) with functions on "facets" (such as edges of triangles).  In this case the integration by parts cannot be carried out over the entire domain $\Omega$, and a means must be found to work with a variational formulation based on *partial* integration by parts on the individual elements.

It is impossible to even scratch the surface of choices available for trial functions and test functions across the various applications of numerical PDEs.  However in many cases the use of piecewise polynomials is preferred because of the simplicity of performing integration with them.

I will finish with a broad and poorly justified generalization.  These topics are intriguing because the analysis of discrete approximations to continuous functions is informed by geometric constructions (mesh generation) whose tradition goes back to Euclid and Archimedes.

Comment: Good answer. To your discussion of quasi-optimal approximation --- the error of approximation also depend on the approximating subspace $V_n$, yes? In a finite element solver, I can make the constant as bad as I want by using very thin triangles in my triangulation.

Comment: @Neal: Yes, the error depends on the triangulation but through the poorness of the approximating subspace's best approximation, not the constant factor relating the coercivity of the bilinear form to the Sobolev norm.